# How does the versioning work here?

Tags: support, edits

How does SO's (or other SE sites) versioning work of questions and answers? Do they use some standard piece of code or is it something homebrew?

With versioning I meant if for example a question is edited you'll see all the changes (a diff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's homebrew, as far as I know (I am sure one of the developers can confirm).

Every version is stored in the database - what you see is the result of some string diff algorithms to show the differences.

I recall Jeff posting about string diff algorithms in this exact context, but can't find a reference.